# how to fix problem with transition-group when rendering list after submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

Actually I'm in trouble with rendering updated list after submitting a form with vue transition-group

There's no problem when I use simple "ul" tag but when I want to make this transition via transition group there's error in console

> " children must be keyed with :li.

```
<transition-group name="list-complete" tag="ul" class="list">
  <li class="item list-complete-item " v-for="contact in contacts" v-bind:key="contact.id">
    <div class="item__desc">
      <p class="paragraph">
        <span class="bold">{{contact.name}}</span>
      </p>
      <p class="paragraph">
        <span class="bold">Mail:</span>
        {{contact.email}}
      </p>
      <p class="paragraph">
        <span class="bold">Street:</span>
        {{contact.address.street}}
      </p>
      <p class="paragraph">
        <span class="bold">City:</span>
        {{contact.address.city}}
      </p>
    </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: `contact.id` could be undefined in one, or more, of the iterations.

Comment: Oh yes, You have right. Incoming items to a list dont have "id" so I changed  v:bind:key to more unique. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind your `key` to unique data like `index` as follows :

```
  <li class="item list-complete-item " v-for="(contact,index) in contacts" v-bind:key="index">
```

As mentioned in the [`official docs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#transition-group) :

> - **Usage:**
>
> `<transition-group>` serve as transition effects for multiple elements/components. >The `<transition-group>` renders a real DOM element. By default it renders a `<span>`, and you can configure what element it should render via the tag attribute.
>
> Note every child in a `<transition-group>` must be **uniquely keyed** for the animations to work properly.